# React rendering JSON nested objects

Tags: json, reactjs

I have this code which works perfectly:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://services2.arcgis.com/sJvSsHKKEOKRemAr/arcgis/rest/services/Bigfoot%20Locations/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
      this.setState({data: myJson.features[0].attributes.STATE_NAME})
      console.log(this.state.data)
      
    });
   }



render() {
       return (
           <div className = ''>
               {this.state.data}
           </div>
       )
   }
}
```

However when I try to make the data set in state more general so that I can render whatever I want like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://services2.arcgis.com/sJvSsHKKEOKRemAr/arcgis/rest/services/Bigfoot%20Locations/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
      this.setState({data: myJson.features})
      console.log(this.state.data)
      
    });
   }



render() {
       return (
           <div className = ''>
               {this.state.data[0].attributes.STATE_NAME}
           </div>
       )
   }
}
```

I get "Cannot read property STATE_NAME of undefined. The only change is that I tried to access the object in the render method instead of ComponentDidMount. What's the issue here?

Comment: There's nothing in the initial state to get a `[0].attributes.STATE_NAME` from

Comment: Doesn't componentDidMount happen before the render though? So before being rendered it would be set to the json data anyways? My current state for data is just set as an empty string.

Comment: But `fetch` does not occur instantaneously - it gets rendered before the new state is set.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, the `render()` function is being called before the data is populated, even though `componentDidMount()` will run before the first render.

What you need is to store an intermediate loading state in your react state to indicate that the data has not yet arrived.

```
class RENAME_ME extends Component {
  state = {
    loaded: false,
    data: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://services2.arcgis.com/sJvSsHKKEOKRemAr/arcgis/rest/services/Bigfoot%20Locations/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json"
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((myJson) => {
        this.setState({
          data: myJson.features[0].attributes.STATE_NAME,
          loaded: true,
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
  }

  render() {
    // Data is still loading, display an intermediate message
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
    return <div className="">{this.state.data}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it had to do something with the data not being loaded in yet but in my mind I thought render wouldn't run until everything in componentDidMount did. But your explanation makes total sense. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem! Make sure you mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't read from the state until it's present:

```
render() {
       return (
           <div className = ''>
               {(this.state.data && this.state.data.length) ? this.state.data[0].attributes.STATE_NAME : `still loading, or maybe an error`}
           </div>
       )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only display the state when it is present so this condition has 2 parts.
First part(this.state.data) is only true when the data is saved in the state so the next part(this.state.data[0].attributes.STATE_NAME) runs after that

```
render() {
   return (
       <div className = ''>
           {this.state.data && this.state.data[0].attributes.STATE_NAME}
       </div>
   )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state 'data' is not properly initialized to handle object maybe

are they initialized like this?

```
this.state = {
     data: []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render the value whenever it is present by
`{this.state.data[0].attributes && this.state.data[0].attributes.STATE_NAME}`